# Configure allowed request formats globally for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I configure the application so that only requests of certain formats are considered when Rails searches for a template to render (e.g. html, and json) without using `respond_to` in each and every action?

Apparently, in Rails 3 it's possible to specify requested response format as a get parameter. E.g. `http://example.com/users/1?format=pdf`. Such requests result in `ActionView::MissingTemplate` errors since there are no templates for that format. I need to set allowed formats globally for the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set it into ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end
```

Then you don't need to set the same in sub class.

**Add**

Not sure if you neglected, when using `respond_to` as class macro, it should be used in pair with `respond_with` in action.

```
# Sample action
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  respond_with @user
end
```

This response is JSON response now.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm not sure if it is even supposed to work like that. Using `respond_to` in action method does the job, but using it on a controller class level - does not affect the result.

Comment: @soundtruck, I wonder if the update could answer your question.

Comment: Updated from 3.2.13 to 3.2.15 - no luck. Also checked on a project with rails 4.0.1 - the same issue.

Comment: just read the update of your answer. Let's assume that application produces html responses only, no json. I need to prohibit all other formats but html, but I'd like to avoid editing each and every action.